# JQuery delete an appended li fom ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, closest

I am having problems deleting a list item `li` from it's parent `ul`. Normally I would do the following:

```
$(this).closest('li').remove();
```

or

```
$(this).parent().remove();
```

As the list items are appended to the page via a form I think there is a problem with the `this` usage.

My code that appends the `li` is as follows:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add_section', function(){
var section_title=$('.section').val();
var menu_type=$('.menu_type_sel').val();
var rest_id=$('body').data('rest_id');
var menu_id=$('body').data('menu_id');
var error=false;
if(section_title=="")
{
    $('.error_box13').eq(2).html("<p>Please Add a Section Title</p>");
    $('.error_box13').eq(2).show(300);
    error=true;
    return;
}

var data="section="+section_title+"&rest_id="+rest_id+"&menu_id="+menu_id+"&menu_type="+menu_type;

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/write_section.php",
    data:data,
    success:function(html){
        if(html!="x")
        {
        var app_section="";
        app_section="<li class='hover' id='menu_"+html+"'>"+section_title+" <a href='javascript:void(0);' class='delete_section' data-id='"+html+"'>[x]</a></li>";
        $(app_section).appendTo('#sortme');
        $('.section').val("");
        }
    }
});//end ajax
});
```

To remove the `li` so far I have:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete_section', function(){
var delete_id=$(this).data('id');
var data="id="+delete_id;
alert(data);
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"includes/delete_section",
    data:data,
    context:this,
    success:function(html){
        if(html!="X")
        {
            $(this).closest('li').remove();
            return false;
        }
    }
});//end ajax
});
```

I have added the `context:` bit as a trial but this still does not delete the `li`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed my stupid error:

The url is missing its .php therefore there is no returned code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the old `var that = this` trick.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete_section', function(){
    var delete_id=$(this).data('id');
    var data="id="+delete_id;
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"includes/delete_section",
        data:data,
        context:this,
        success:function(html){
            if(html!="X")
            {
                $(that).closest('li').remove();
                return false;
            }
        }
    });//end ajax
});
```

Comment: I actually thought this above would work but still no luck. It may be noting that the `li` elements are sortable/dragable using jquery_ui.js